# Python How can I send an ICMP packet without spoofing?

Tags: python, scapy, packet, icmp

I am trying to send an ICMP packet in python using scapy using my Debian VPS but I am not trying to spoof the IP or anything, but since my server doesn't spoof it won't send it anyways, but I cannot figure out any other way to create an ICMP packet and send it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an IP and an ICMP layer, like this:

```
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, ICMP
DESTINATION = "192.168.111.4"
packet = IP(dst=DESTINATION, ttl=20) / ICMP()
# print(packet)
```

Comment: Would this require a server that spoofs?

Comment: You usually need to be root for crafting any sort of packet.